# Bind Two DataGridView ComboBoxColumn to the same Datasource

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView with two ComboBoxColumns.

One shall show ID of a Person and the other the Name of the same person.

I want to bound both to the same DataSource so both will be Synchronized.

When I use the same DataSource for a regular ComboBox (not inside a DataGridView), it's synchronized. Why isn't it Synchronized when using it inside a DataGridView?